# ARIMA modeling: can seasonal data be seasonally stationary?

Tags: arima, seasonality, unit-root

I am new to ARIMA modeling and currently encountering a weird situation with time series of count data. The time plot shows clear seasonal patterns.ACF also hints on presence of seasonality. However, seasonal unit root test in R shows that series is seasonally stationary.

If I include seasonal differencing (D=1), I cannot find a single model where residuals  satisfy normality assumption, even if I perform log- or - square root- or Box-Cox transformations of original series. If I do not include seasonal differencing (keeping seasonal AR and MA parameters is in the model), I easily identify a model with great diagnostics (residuals are white noise and normally distributed).

Having hard time solving the puzzle whether seasonal-looking data can be seasonally stationary. Will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Hello Jane, may I ask you which test you applied? Was it 'nsdiffs' from 'forecast' package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it's simply that clear seasonal correlations don't always imply that you need seasonal *differencing*; the seasonal effect can be modelled fine with seasonal moving average & autoregressive terms.  It's the same in non-seasonal models; just because you see a strong autocorrelation doesn't necessarily mean you need to difference the series.  Sounds like you solved the 'puzzle' by fitting a good model to the undifferenced series that still incorporated seasonal effects.

Comment: Many thanks Scortchi for your help! Now I am not worried about differencing.